# How to obtain details (validity, number of entries) on a Singaporean eVisa?

Tags: visas, transit, singapore, e-visas

Recently my buddy applied for a Singapore visa as he had to transit in SG and during one return leg of the journey had about 6 hours to kill in SG. The SG embassy sent back his Indian Passport (with no visa stamp in it) along with a letter which said he has been granted an eVisa (Multiple entry) and that this letter should be produced before commencing the journey at the airlines boarding counter.

Now we are not sure if this visa is only valid for this particular journey? Or is it just an unlimited multiple entries visa with no expiry date (there are no dates mentioned in the eVisa letter)? This eVisa thing is so different than how the US visas (B1/B2/H1) are stamped in the passport and being our first experience with eVisa, we are just confused.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [website](https://www.psi.gov.sg/NASApp/tmf/TMFServlet?app=SAVE-PUBLIC&fromOVAL=true&isNew=true&Reload=true) dedicated to check the Singaporean eVisa status. Enter the visa and the passport number and you should get all the details about the eVisa.

Comment: After logging in to that link, it asks for a Sing Pass Id, which is neither mentioned in the eVisa nor do we have a Sing Pass Id from else where. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @happybuddha This should be your FIN, mentioned on the e-visa authorisation email.